# Rigorous proof of this assertion about Pascal's Triangle

Tags: combinatorics

I have noticed that it seems that there are no prime numbers in Pascal's Triangle that are not directly adjacent to the number 1. Is there a rigorous proof for this assertion?

Comment: I can't think of a proof of the fact right now, but yes, this is correct.

Comment: Do you know Lucas' formula for the number of times a prime divides a factorial?

Comment: How would that apply here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is quite easy to show that for $n\ge 4$ and $2\le r \le n-2$ both: $$\binom nr\gt n$$

And that the prime factors of $\binom nr$ are all less than or equal to $n$. So $\binom nr$ cannot be prime.

Comment: Clarification on the first step would be helpful.

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce Various ways to do it, including induction. Once the middle items in Pascal's Triangle are greater than $n$ you are always adding two terms which are greater than or equal to $n$ to get the terms in the $(n+1)^{th}$ line, and $2n\gt n+1$.

Comment: @AidanF.Pierce Another way is to note that either $r$ or $n-r$ is less than or equal to $\frac n2$, (say $r$ for convenience) so that $\binom nr =\frac n1\cdot \frac {n-1}2 \dots \frac {n-r+1}r$ is $n$ times a product of factors which are each individually greater than or equal to $1$.